# How to replace a whole div with an other with preg_replace regEx

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

i don't get it how to replace a div with an other in PHP preg_replace

```
$string ='
  <div id="myid">this has to be replaced</div>
  <p>here is something</p>
  <div id="any">any text not to be replaced</div>
';
```

if i do

```
$string = preg_replace('/<div id=\"myid\">.*<\/div>/','anything',$string);
```

it does not work and i don't get why?!

Comment: Because quantifiers are greedy by default. Have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html. Better yet: Use an HTML parser and DOM manipulation to do whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `regex` [is working fine](http://regexr.com?3427l) I suspect that you didn't assign the return value of `preg_replace` to any variables.

```
$string = preg_replace('/<div id=\"myid\">.*<\/div>/','anything',$string);
```

should work.

---

After you edited your question:

As [@Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) mentioned, `.*` is greedy, that means it matches everything until the last match. You can use the non-greedy quantifier (ie. `.*?`). The following [should work](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QfPqS6):

```
$string = preg_replace('/<div id=\"myid\">.*?<\/div>/','anything',$string);
```

Comment: hmm, on RegExr it does work but my php script does return only a blank string.